# Filter out the stage or inside the stage

Tags: jenkins

I havent had much luck with google due to the phrasing of the question so I apologize for the very basic question.

If i have 3 build stages setup in my jenkinsfile and stages 1 and 3 always run, but 2 only runs if its a PR, do I make it keep the stage but not run the command, or just filter out the whole stage?

```
stage {
  if (env.isPR) {
    sh()
```

or more like

```
if (env.isPR) {
  stage {
    sh()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you filter out the whole stage, then after a non-PR build, the stage visualization on the build page will remove that PR stage (for all builds, even the ones which in fact did run the PR stage).

So, from a visualization perspective, I would suggest that you retain the stage.

```
stage {
  if (env.isPR) {
    sh()
```